# How do I fit experimental data to an ODE (michaelis-menten) equation to get the constants?

Tags: matlab, ode, data-fitting

I'm trying to get the kf kr and kcat from the ODE equations given by the derivation of the Michaelis-Menten equation. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michaelis%E2%80%93Menten_kinetics).
I have experimental data form a simulation and the aproximate values of the k. I need to get a good fit for the k and I don't know how to do it, I try with lsqcurvefit the problem is that I have 2 equations and too many variables and I couldn't find any example of sth similar. If u execute the code u can see both plots the one of the equation and the experimental but I dont know how to put it together.

Thank you in advance

[(plot taked from the code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPVSu.png)

```
close all; clear all; clc

%Michaelis Menten Kinetics
%Simple Model for Single Substrate Catalyzed Reactions

% Initial Data
global e0 s0 c0 volum
volum=50^3;
e0=10/volum;
s0=500/volum;
c0=0;

% Load experimental data
data=dlmread("rk_output.txt");

% Assign the data vectors
global timeR subs enz compl prod

timeR=data(:,2);            % time
subs=data(:,3)/volum;       % Substrate
enz=data(:,4)/volum;        % Enzyme
compl=data(:,5)/volum;      % Complex
prod=data(:,6)/volum;       % Product

% Unknown coefficients
global k
k=[1.66, 7.1E-4, 3.5E-4];   %k1 k2 k-1 

% Fitting Curves to Data using Nonlinear Regression
fun=@(t,sc) [k(3)*sc(2)-k(1)*sc(1)*(e0-sc(2)); k(1)*sc(1)*(e0-sc(2))-(k(3)+k(2))*sc(2) ];

time_period=linspace(0,1000,500);
initial=[s0,c0];
[t,sc]=ode45(fun,time_period,initial);

% Assign the data vectors
substrate=sc(:,1);
complex=sc(:,2);
enzyme=(e0-complex);
product=(initial(1)-substrate-complex);

% Plot the raw data
figure(1)
plot(timeR,enz,timeR,compl,t,enzyme,t,complex)
xlabel ('time (ns)')
ylabel ('Particles')
title ('Figure 1')
legend('EnzymeReal','ComplexReal','Enzyme','Complex')
```

Comment: Your question does not seem to be about programming and thus off-topic here. It may be a good fit for [scicomp.se] though.

Comment: That should be done by a simple least square fit. you solve the ODEs for a set of parameters, compare to data, change, etc. Can you tell more precisely where the problem is? Try to give a Minimum Working Example by using either a small generic data set or provide the data.

Comment: Moreover, while it is somewhat interesting to read the wiki article, maybe you can simplify the work by stating precisely the ODEs that should provide the solution to your data.